# SCRIPT1014: Invalid character - Quote symbol

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, invalid-characters

I have this problem:

array[i].idAuthor is a String variable. I want to pass this String to a function which is called inside an append-String.

The code works fine in Chrome and Firefox except for Internet Explorer. IE gives me this error: SCRIPT1014: Invalid character

I think the issue are the **`-Quotes**.

I hope the following example helps to express my problem.

```
<script>
(...)
    $("#id").append("<div onClick='myFunc(`" + array[i].idAuthor + "`);'>" + i + "</div>");
(...)
<script>
```

Is there another way to handle my situation or to replace the `-Quotes with another character that is compatible with IE?

Answer (score 10):

It looks like you're putting backticks (`) into your string there.

```
onClick='myFunc(`" + ... + "`);'>
```

In modern browsers, backticks are used for [template literals.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) IE11 doesn't support template literals.

Instead, try escaping your quotes:

```
onClick='myFunc(\"" + array[i].idAuthor + "\");'>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use normal quotes, but escape them so they are parsed as part of the string:

```
$("#id").append("<div onClick='myFunc(\"" + array[i].idAuthor + "\");'>" + i + "</div>");
//------------------------------------^^   ----------------------^^
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//create element using jquery
var elm = $('<div>');

//put ID as custom attribute
elm.attr('data-author-id', array[i].idAuthor);

//put some html content for new element
elm.html(i);

// catch click on it
elm.click(function(){
    // call external function and pass your custom tag attribute as value
    myFunc( $(this).attr('data-author-id') );
});

    $("#id").append(elm);
```

something like that should work.

of more shot way:

```
$("#id").append($('<div>')
.attr('data-author-id', array[i].idAuthor)
.html(i)
.click(function(){
    // call external function and pass your custom tag attribute as value
    myFunc( $(this).attr('data-author-id') );
}));
```

jQuery have lot of functionality control tag attributes, events, values and lot's of useful stuff.