# SCRIPT1014: Invalid Character Grave Accent (`) IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-objects

have serious problems with IE browser.
For the Firefox & Chrome browser everything is normal.

```
let currentDateFormat = clone.beginDate.format('dddd DD'),
    $thead = $(`table#${week}`).find('thead');

clone.strDay += `<td id="${currentDateFormat.replace(/ /g, '')}"></td>`
$thead.find(`tr:nth-child(2) th:nth-child(${child})`).text(currentDateFormat);
child += 1;
```

I have seen solutions, but it does not work for me.

-> `

to be:

\"

Comment: IE does not support template literals.

Comment: Template literals are not supported at all in any version of IE. Don't use them.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Browser_compatibility

Comment: If you mean [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37332381/4642212), the solutions tell you to use _normal_ quotes. `\"` worked in that context. You need reguar quotes with regular string concatenation.